# Using Padding with Text and Style

Tags: output-formatting, text

Suppose that I use:

```
Text[Style["(1, 0, 0)", 12, Background -> White], {1, 1, 0}]
```

How can I put a few points of padding around the text?

**Thanks to Jens:**

Initialization cell:

Options[myText] = {Background -> White, Padding -> 1, 
   FrameStyle -> None};

```
myText[s_, pos_, OptionsPattern[]] := 
 Text[Framed[Style[s, 12], Background -> OptionValue[Background], 
   FrameMargins -> OptionValue[Padding], 
   FrameStyle -> OptionValue[FrameStyle]], pos]
```

Image code using myText:

```
Show[
 ContourPlot3D[{z == Sqrt[x^2 + y^2]}, {x, -2.5, 2.5}, {y, -2.5, 
   2.5}, {z, 0, 2},
  ContourStyle -> {Yellow, Opacity[0.8]}, Mesh -> None],
 ParametricPlot3D[{r Cos[t], r Sin[t], 2}, {t, 0, 2 π}, {r, 0, 2},
   PlotStyle -> {Blue, Opacity[0.5]}, Mesh -> None],
 ParametricPlot3D[{r Cos[t], r Sin[t], 0}, {t, 0, 2 π}, {r, 0, 2},
   PlotStyle -> {LightBlue, Opacity[0.5]}, Mesh -> None],
 Graphics3D[{
   Red, Thick, Arrow[{{0, 0, 0}, {2, 2, 0}}],
   Black, PointSize[Large],
   Point[{{0, 0, 0}, 2 {Cos[Pi/4], Sin[Pi/4], 0}}],
   myText["r = 0", {0, -0.6, 0}],
   myText["r = 2", 2 {Cos[30 °], Sin[30 °], 0}],
   Red, Thick, 
   Arrow[{{Cos[Pi/4], Sin[Pi/4], 0}, {Cos[Pi/4], Sin[Pi/4], 2.5}}],
   Black, PointSize[Large],
   Point[{{Cos[Pi/4], Sin[Pi/4], 0}, {Cos[Pi/4], Sin[Pi/4], 
      1}, {Cos[Pi/4], Sin[Pi/4], 2}}],
   myText["z = r", {Cos[35 °], Sin[35 °], 0.8}],
   myText["z = 2", {Cos[35 °], Sin[35 °], 1.8}]
   }], AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "z"}, 
 PlotRange -> {{-2.5, 2.5}, {-2.5, 2.5}, {0, 2.5}}
 ]
```

For some reason, I am getting frequent kernel beeps when running the cell containing the image code. I don't know why.

[image]

Comment: Could you provide some context for your problem?  E.g. Are you trying to include this text inside a graphic, or is it intended to be free-standing?

Comment: @MarcoB Jens has the idea that I need. Thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are two alternatives I would suggest, depending on what your plans for the `Background` are. Here is an illustration:

```
Text[Pane[Style["(1, 0, 0)", 12, Background -> Yellow], 
  ImageMargins -> 10], {1, 1, 0}]
```

[image: small background]

```
Text[Framed[Style["(1, 0, 0)", 12], Background -> Yellow, 
  FrameMargins -> 10, FrameStyle -> None], {1, 1, 0}]
```

[image: big background]

The first solution uses a `Pane`, but this doesn't have a `Background` option so that you have to specify the background color in the `Style` command, as you already did. I changed it to yellow just for clarity.

The second solution assumes that you want the background to fill out the extra space that was created, too. This can be done with `Frame` because it allows the `Background` option. I then set `FrameStyle -> None` to make the result look otherwise indistinguishable from a `Pane`.

When used in `Graphics3D`, these two outputs look as follows:

[image: pane]

[image]

To make this easier to use, just define something like this:

```
Options[myText] = {Background -> White, Padding -> 5, 
   FrameStyle -> None};

myText[s_, pos_, OptionsPattern[]] := 
 Text[Framed[Style[s, 12], Background -> OptionValue[Background], 
   FrameMargins -> OptionValue[Padding], 
   FrameStyle -> OptionValue[FrameStyle]], pos]

Graphics3D[myText["{1,0,0}", {0, 0, 0}], Background -> LightBlue]
```

[image: function]

The relevant options can be changed by adding them to in the invocation of `myText`. I used the name `Padding` for the option that you wanted, even though it's realized as `FrameMargins` internally.

Comment: I think this is what I need. However, that's a lot of stuff to type each time you want to put a label in your diagram. Is it possible for a single line of code (and where to put it, initialization or whatever) so that every time I typed something like Text["(1,0,0)",{1,0,0}] all that other stuff would get filled in? Or is there a way to minimize some of it? Thanks for the help.

Comment: Sure, your best bet is to define a function. I'll add that...

Comment: Did you define myText as you did with all those OptionValues so that you can override the options later with something like `Options[myText] = {Background -> Yellow, Padding -> 1, 
   FrameStyle -> None};` And would you put your original code in initialization cells at the top of your notebook or what?

Comment: Yes to both. E.g., try `Graphics3D[myText["{1,0,0}",{0,0,0},Padding->20,Background->Directive[Opacity[.5],Red]],Background->LightBlue]`. Or `SetOptions[myText,Background->LightOrange]`.

Comment: Showed an example of how I am using your idea. See my original post above.