# Using Padding and Margins with Graphics object

Tags: graphics, manipulate, options, grid-layouts

I have relatively simple question. I need to control size and background color of the following two zones separately (indicated by blue and magenta arrows on the figure).

[image]

Using `Framed` options I can control margins and background color of the whole zone.

**Question** Can I choose a color of the zone shown with blue arrow separately? (It can be changed by `PlotRangePadding`). 
Put it differently, how to address the "border" of the graphics object highlighted with the gray arrow?

Code snippet to play around is below:

```
Manipulate[
 Framed[GraphicsGrid[{
    {
     Graphics3D[Background -> Green, ImagePadding -> 20], 
     Graphics3D[Background -> Yellow, ImagePadding -> 0]
     }
    }, Background -> LightGray, ImageSize -> {400, 200}, 
   Frame -> True, PlotRangePadding -> {a, b}],
  FrameStyle -> Red, FrameMargins -> 30, Background -> White
  ]

 , {{a, 20}, 0, 20, 1, Appearance -> "Labeled"}
 , {{b, 20}, 0, 20, 1, Appearance -> "Labeled"}
 ]
```

Why? I need this functionality to use with screen-recording software.

There is also a related question [91739](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/91739/using-padding-with-text-and-style).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think adding another frame will do what you want. Like so:

```
Manipulate[
  Framed[
    Framed[
      GraphicsGrid[
        {{Graphics3D[Background -> Green, ImagePadding -> 20], 
          Graphics3D[Background -> Yellow, ImagePadding -> 0]}},
         Background -> LightGray,
         ImageSize -> {400, 200},
         Frame -> True],
      FrameStyle -> None,
      Background -> Red,
      FrameMargins -> {{a, a}, {b, b}}],
    FrameStyle -> {Red, AbsoluteThickness[2]},
    FrameMargins -> 30,
    Background -> White],
  {{a, 20}, 0, 20, 1, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
  {{b, 20}, 0, 20, 1, Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

[image: framing]

Answer (score 7):

You can use [`Show`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Show.html) to modify the background of the [`Graphics`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Graphics.html) expression returned by [`GraphicsGrid`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GraphicsGrid.html):

```
Manipulate[
 Framed[
  Show[
   GraphicsGrid[
    {{Graphics3D[Background -> Green, ImagePadding -> 20], 
      Graphics3D[Background -> Yellow, ImagePadding -> 0]}},
    Background -> LightGray,
    ImageSize -> {400, 200}, Frame -> True, 
    PlotRangePadding -> {a, b}
    ],
   Background -> Red
   ],
  FrameStyle -> Red, FrameMargins -> 30, Background -> White
  ],
 {{a, 20}, 0, 20, 1, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {{b, 20}, 0, 20, 1, Appearance -> "Labeled"}
 ]
```

[image]

This works because `GraphicsGrid` returns a `Graphics` expression with the contents placed as [`Inset`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Inset.html). The `Background` specified in the options to `GraphicsGrid` is implemented using [`Rectangle`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Rectangle.html) directives, since it needs to be flexible enough to support coloring of individual grid cells, which also explains why the `PlotRangePadding` is added "around" the background.

Comment: thank you, your answer is nice, I wish I could choose both.